# Calculate the exact value of an infinite sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$1 + \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{...}}}$$ I think I need to convert that sequence to sequence in terms of n and then evaluate $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}$$ but I'm really stuck into converting it.

Comment: If you denote your sequence as $x$, note that $x=1+\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: It might be easier to work with the numerators and denominators separately. If you write the $n$-th and $(n+1)$-th terms as $p_n/q_n$ and $p_{n+1}/q_{n+1}$ and work out the $(n+2)$-th term you will see that the $p_n$ and $q_n$ follow a very well known sequence, Fibonacci's. Then you can pass to [their explicit expression in terms of $n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression).

Answer (score 3):

By noting that $…=r$, then I would start from the end

$$\frac{1}{…}=\frac{1}{r}$$
$$1+\frac{1}{…}=1+\frac{1}{r}=\frac{r+1}{r}$$
Skipping one step,
$$1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{…}}=1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{r}}=\frac{2r+1}{r+1}$$
Next steps render $$s_3=\frac{3r+2}{2r+1}$$
$$s_4=\frac{5r+3}{3r+2}$$
$$s_n=\frac{f_n \cdot r+f_{n-1}}{f_{n-1}\cdot r +f_{n-2}}$$, where $f_n$ are the terms of the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: Exactly. And the limit of $s_n$ is indeed $\varphi$, the golden ratio.

Answer (score 2):

Like @mowzorn said, it is a good idea to let $$x=1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\ldots}}$$ so that $x=1+\frac{1}{x}$.

You will see that there are two values of $x$ for which this works - $\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$ and $\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}$. It seems strange that this expression could have two different values. You can argue that only $\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$ is a valid solution but you could also argue that $\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}$ is a solution to your problem. 3Blue1Brown made a video on this, using differentiation to show the two perspectives - the link is here: [The other way to visualize derivatives | Chapter 12, Essence of calculus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CfW845LNObM&list=PLZHQObOWTQDMsr9K-rj53DwVRMYO3t5Yr&index=12).